# Get User Path When Using Double Backslash (Python)

Tags: python, path, pickle, absolute-path

I am looking to find a way to get the current username in a path when the path has double backslashes. Here is my example code:

```
import getpass
import pickle

no_user_path = pickle.load(open("C:\\Users\\{}\\Desktop\\data.dat", "rb"))
path = no_user_path.format(getpass.getuser())

print(path)
```

Here I am trying to navigate to a path while using the pickle module but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mikur/Desktop/help.py", line 4, in <module>
    no_user_path = pickle.load(open("C:\\Users\\{}\\Desktop\\data.dat", "rb"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\{}\\Desktop\\data.dat'
>>>
```

As you can see it does not actually replace the `{}` with the username, why is it not doing that? It works fine with only one backslash but that is an escape character and causes an error for `pickle`.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your string before calling `pickle.load()`

```
import getpass
import pickle

data = "C:\\Users\\{}\\Desktop\\data.dat".format(getpass.getuser())

no_user_path = pickle.load(open(data, "rb"))
```